# Python Generics: cannot be assigned to declared type "T@func"

Tags: python, pylance, pyright

I'm trying to introduce Generic typing to a function of mine, but am getting a pylance error of:

```
Expression of type "A" cannot be assigned to declared type "T@func"
  Type "A" cannot be assigned to type "T@func"
```

I've reduce my problem in my code to this simplified version:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union, List


class A:
    def __init__(self, arg: str) -> None:
        self.arg = arg


class B:
    def __init__(self, arg: int) -> None:
        self.arg = arg


T = TypeVar("T", A, B)


def getA() -> A:
    return A("a")


def getB() -> B:
    return B(1)


def func(arg: T) -> T:
    out: T
    if isinstance(arg, A):
        out = getA()
    elif isinstance(arg, B):
        out = getB()

    return out


print(func(A("a")))
```

The error occurs at both `out = getA()` and `out = getB()`

is pyright not able to accurately infer types here? Am I making a mistake?

Comment: I tried this in PyCharm and all looks good. If I change T's definition to `T = TypeVar("T", A, str)`, then `out=getB()` line gives a warning - so it works correctly. I suppose it's an issue of your type checker.

Comment: i'm wondering when generics is needed in python, since python is dynamic typing?

Comment: @LeiYang You can add static type analysis to python using PyRight. Definitely helpful when working in a larger team and you need more concrete contracts between functions.

Comment: @michcio1234 Do you know if you are using pyright?  When I manually run this file through pyright I get the same error, so its not my vscode pylance plugin

Answer (score 0):

When you bind `T` to `func` via `arg`, you are saying `T` is the type of `arg` in `func`. When you declare `out` as a `T`, you are saying `out` will always be the same type as `arg`. So by assinging the result of `getA` to `out`, you are assigning something you know is an `A` to a `T`, but `out` must be a `B` if `arg` is a `B`.

To avoid the type errors, you can just write `func` like this:

```py
def func(arg: T) -> T:
    if isinstance(arg, A):
        return getA()
    if isinstance(arg, B):
        return getB()
```

Within your conditions, you actually have narrowed the type of `arg` to `A` and `B`, so if you return inside the conditions, you know you are returning a `T`, i.e. the same type as `arg`.

Comment: The warning remains even if I remove `B` from the code. It seems as if pyright does not infer that `A` is a valid generic `T` even though `T` is bound to `A`.